# How do I make mutt show Cyrillic characters on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, locale, mutt, i18n

I'm using `mutt-1.5.21p0v0` to read my mail on OpenBSD 5.2 every now and then.

Why does `mutt` show question marks instead of Cyrillic characters when I open standards-compliant email messages in Russian?

Comment: Console or X11?

Comment: PuTTY; but the problem is specifically with `mutt` -- for example, `cat` shows Cyrillic symbols in `koi8-r` just fine, without any problems.  It's `mutt` that seems to automatically translate all non-ascii characters to the ascii character of `?`.

Answer (score 3):

http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttFaq/Charset

You have to decide on a locale and a character set.

For a list of locales and their corresponding character sets, see `/usr/share/locale/` on OpenBSD.  There is no mix-and-matching between languages and charsets, apart from what's in that directory.  However, the language and charset are controlled by `LANG` and various more specific `LC_` environmental variables, which can be set independent of each other to potentially have the exact effects desired.

In order to just change the character set, and not the language of the menus or any other options, only `LC_CTYPE` has to be modified.  For example, in PuTTY *Window* → *Translation*, set `Remote character set` to either *KOI8-R* or *UTF-8*, and then run `mutt` as either `env LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.KOI8-R mutt` or `env LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 mutt` (assuming a C-shell), respectively.